# How do I replace Deprecated httpClient.getParams() CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE with RequestConfig?

Tags: java

I have inherited the code

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(
                CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(parameter, "utf-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        if(headers != null){
            Set<String> headersKey = headers.keySet();
            for (String key : headersKey) {
                httpPost.setHeader(key, headers.get(key));
            }
        }
        return httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

`httpClient.getParams()` is @Deprecated and reads "

There are no class docs for RequestConfig and I do not know what method should be used to replace `httpPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter` and `CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE`

Answer (score 1):

It can be set when you create httpClient, try this:

```
RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(CONN_TIMEOUT)
                       .setExpectContinueEnabled(false).build();  
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig)
                       .build();
```

Comment: I want time out to be infinite similar to below two lines of code. hence what is the value for `CONN_TIMEOUT` in the above code?

`client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(0));
 client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.stalecheck", new  Boolean(true));`